# Select an Object with jQuery and add multiple functions to it, using (this)

Tags: jquery

This will probably sound silly, but I want to optimize my jQuery code in order to achieve something like this:

```
jQuery("#myid).{ // Here, how can I make it work?
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    if(value == null || value == ""){
     jQuery(this).addClass("error");
    }
    // and so on
}
```

**Basically, I want to select a DOM element and apply various codes to it.**
How can I do it?

Comment: Ty guys, the idea is to add as many operations as I want - select the object once and than access it using (this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it to a variable:

```
var $elem = jQuery("#myid");
var value = $elem.val();

if (value == null || value == ""){
    $elem.addClass("error");
}
```

You could also use `.each()`, as it'll iterate only over your single element, but it's somewhat confusing in my opinion:

```
jQuery("#myid").each(function(){
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    if(value == null || value == ""){
     jQuery(this).addClass("error");
    }
    // and so on
})
```

Comment: `#myid` and `.each`? I don't think it works well as jQuery would return single element when it looks a `#` which is going to use `.getElementById`.

Comment: @Vega: You can iterate over the set of matched elements. The selector still returns a jQuery object.

Comment: Ty, the idea is to add as many operations as I want - select the object once and than access it using (this) - So the assign into variable looks pretty good

Answer (score 1):

Use the anonymous function:

```
jQuery("#myid").addClass(function(){   // To addClass
     return this.value ? 'error' : '';
}).css('width', function() {           // For css
     return this.value || 400;
}).attr("id", function () {            // For attribute change
     return "newID";
});
```

Comment: I don't think `this.value` can return `null`, so you can just do `this.value ? 'error' : ''`.

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have operation more than addClass, use `.each`

```
$("#myid").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == null || value == ""){
      $(this).addClass("error");
    }
    // and so on
});
```